# theano.tensor.nlinalg.svd(X) with 3D input array

Tags: python, theano, svd

I would like to perform svd on multiple 2D arrays collected in a single 3D array with theano as it can easily be done with numpy by:

```
U, S, V = numpy.linalg.svd(X)
```

I tried:

```
U, S, V = theano.tensor.nlinalg.svd(X)
```

But, it seems `theano.tensor.nlinalg.svd` only accepts 2D arrays and it is not able to compute multiple svds in the same time:

```
assert x.ndim == 2, "The input of svd function should be a matrix."AssertionError: 
The input of svd function should be a matrix.
```

Being curious if there is any way around to take the same functionality from `theano.tensor.nlinalg.svd()` as we have with `numpy.linalg.svd()` for 3D arrays.

Thanks.